# Вывод секунд в реальном времени

Tags: java

Пытаюсь реализовать метод который будет вы водить секунды в консоль до определенного времени. Например сейчас 20:47:25, хочу что бы выводились секунды 26,27,28,29 и на 30-ой прекращался вывод. Язык JAVA. Мой код выводит почему-то только значение времени которое было во время компиляции,и дальше не идёт.

```
    static void refreshTime() {

    Date date = new Date();
    while (true)
    {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {           
            e.printStackTrace();        
        }

        do {    
            System.out.println(date.getSeconds());          
        } while (date.getSeconds() == 30);
    }

}
```

Comment: Замените `==` на `!=`.

Comment: В таком случае программа выводит просто бесконечный цикл из значения секунды в момент компиляции. То есть если я запустил программу в 12 секунд, выводится бесконечно "12"

Comment: Уже разобрался, спасибо.

Comment: Время не в момент компиляции, а в момент запуска. Перенесите `date` внутрь цикла.